# Convert chef cookbook part to ansible

Tags: ansible, chef-infra

Could you please help me to convert this part of chef cookbook into ansible?

```
node['my']['domains'].each do |domain|
  execute 'install cert' do
    command "/root/bin/my_install.sh --domains #{domain}"
    not_if { File.exists?("/home/my/#{domain}/fulltext.txt") }
  end
end
```

I tried to play with that:

```
- name: Check that the fulltext.txt exists
  stat:
    path: "/home/my/{{ item }}/fulltext.txt"
  loop: "{{ my_domains }}"
  register: stat_result

- name: install cript
  command: "/root/bin/my_install.sh --domains {{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ my_domains }}"
  when: not stat_result.stat.exists
```

but without success.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `without success` => can you please be more specific? What makes the result different from your expectation?

Comment: Here is the error message: "The conditional check 'not stat_result.stat.exists' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (not stat_result.stat.exists): 'str object' has no attribute 'stat'

Comment: This should go in an edit to your question, not in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want the second `loop:` to iterate across the `stat_result.results` list, since each member of that list contains two relevant fields: `item`, containing the original iteration key, and then the `stat` structure that you are expecting (it looks like this, which you can see for yourself with `- debug: var=stat_result`)

```json
ok: [localhost] => {
    "stat_result": {
        "changed": false,
        "msg": "All items completed",
        "results": [
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                "changed": false,
                "failed": false,
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "checksum_algorithm": "sha1",
                        "follow": false,
                        "get_attributes": true,
                        "get_checksum": true,
                        "get_md5": false,
                        "get_mime": true,
                        "path": "/home/my/alpha/fulltext.txt"
                    }
                },
                "item": "alpha",
                "stat": {
                    "exists": false
                }
            },
...
```

thus:

```yaml
- name: install cript
  command: "/root/bin/my_install.sh --domains {{ item.item }}"
  loop: "{{ stat_result.results }}"
  when: not item.stat.exists
```

if you find the expression `item.item` confusing, you can rename the loop variable to be `stat_item` (or whatever makes sense to you) via [`loop_control:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#defining-inner-and-outer-variable-names-with-loop-var)

Answer (score 0):

The attribute [creates](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/command_module.html#parameter-creates) makes the task idempotent. Quoting

> *"If a matching file already exists, this step will not be run."*

For example

```yaml
- name: install cript
  command:
    cmd: "/root/bin/my_install.sh --domains {{ item }}"
    creates: "/home/my/{{ item }}/fulltext.txt"
  loop: "{{ my_domains }}"
```